# Facebook Graph high resolution photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing a Facebook Graph API call for "me/home" to get the user's news feed. As everyone knows, the URL you get in the "picture" field is a low resolution photo that doesn't look good at anything above 100x100. I know you can get the URL to the high resolution picture by doing another graph call for the "object_id" and using the "source" field in that result.

But I was looking at the URLs and thought there might be a way to transform one into the other without having to make another graph call. Either that, or construct the high resolution one from existing data in other fields. For example, the first URL is the low resolution one, and the second URL is the source resolution.

```
http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/297313_10152643117455790_610095553_s.jpg
http://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/297313_10152643117455790_610095553_n.jpg
```

It looks like the numbers are `(something I don't know)_("object_id")_(something else I don't know)`

Has anyone had experience with trying to change out the URLs while still keeping the numerical section in the middle? Are there typically variations that could cause regex problems?

EDIT: Here is the code I'm using.

```
String objectId = null;
if (jsonObject.has("object_id")) {
    objectId = jsonObject.getString("object_id");
}
String postPhoto = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + objectId + "/picture";
```

The check for if the post is a photo is a little earlier in the code, so it'll always run these lines for a post type of "photo".

Answer (score 9):

`me/home` - graph api has some a field called `"object_id" and "type"`. If the type is "photo" then you will have this object_id value.  By Using this object id and make another graph api call then you will get an objecty called `"images"`. This object has several options ( different sizes ).

OR

Use object id like below and get a album sized version of a photo. and the supported types for this call are "thumbnail, normal, album".

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id-from-feed}/picture?type=normal
```

and also checkout this link under [Examples of Supported Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/) section.

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution is what I was trying to avoid (making two graph calls, one after the other). The second one may, work as long as the picture quality is high enough. I'll have to try it tonight.

Comment: I tried it didn't work so I removed the "?type=normal" expansion. Doing that loaded the stock Facebook question mark image for the majority of all the images except for a couple that actually loaded the correct ones.

Comment: me/home will return news feed values, so please check for the post type. if its "Photo" you will have the object_id value using that you can call this in your url to get the images.

Comment: That's just what I'm doing. I updated the post with a little bit of code.

Comment: the question mark images showing because this call "https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id-from-feed}/picture" doen't have permission. try add access_token with this url.

Comment: Make sure to be using the object_id, not just the id! That was messing me up. See related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33765417/264031

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is (Graph API):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=picture.height(961) 
// all any height which u want
```

or (for other user)

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?fields=picture.height(961) 
// replace {user_id} with the user id you want
```

UPDATE :

Since Facebook API will keep updating, This solution may be deprecated. This workaround solution might not work in future.

**You may also need Access Token to execute this endpoint.**

Comment: can you link the documentation to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
/user_id/?fields=picture.height(961)
```

It will give the maximum possible resolution picture.

Answer (score 0):

Its a late response but but I have found a better approach

If you have got a address by using graph api like this

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t1.0-9/s130x130/10501892_701590943222768_782659935906208443_n.png
```

then just replace 130x130 to a valid resolution

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t1.0-9/s480x480/10501892_701590943222768_782659935906208443_n.png
```

and you will be able to get high resolution image

Valid image resolution can be found from this example call

http://graph.facebook.com/701586786556517

701586786556517 = object_id from Facebook graph API call

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found an even better way. If the URL has `_s.jpg`, replace it with `_n.jpg`. If it already has `_n.jpg`, most of the time it will still be low res. In that case just remove the `/130x130` and you get the full resolution almost always.

Comment: Yes you are right, but my approach also give you more flexibility

Comment: Yes. I've found some that have values other than `s130x130`, such as `s50x50` or `p130x130`. So I used a regex to remove that. Again, this is all to avoid having to make another graph call using `object_id`.

Comment: None of these work anymore when I tried them. Is there a better way? This is the one I tried with. https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10641176_10103552900116567_8059447106995328461_n.jpg?oh=0c2c74e34d8e52461a03190e01e396c9&oe=54B6A2BD&__gda__=1421461570_7b723bd3bd459602f2ef6b199c9e76a1

Comment: paste a link of this image on facebook  IMHO above logic is still valid

Comment: hackery no longer work. it seems some sort of finger printing is implemented. Now who can reverse engineer the process and share it :)

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/11072049_10152764274597291_4276545584086361517_n.jpg?oh=c1eda8d703c9efeadbb6e767b7f5229c&oe=55B3235A

Comment: When doing the `me/home` graph call add `fields=attachments` to the end. That'll give an array of attachments with a `src` buried down a few levels for hi-res images.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason none of the answers to this question worked, however, one person on another forum posted to use "full_picture" in the fields perameter and it worked like a charm. I didn't find this in any of the docs...unless I just overlooked it?

OP
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-the-full-size-of-image-in-a-Facebook-post-using-Graph-API

Comment: An external link can provide a real and correct answer but you must put the main code here. If in the future that link is broken the rest of users will have an useless answer

Comment: The answer from the Quora post that works like a charm was this http://graph.facebook.com/<username or userid>/picture?height=1080&width=1080
1080 can be changed to any size you want

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, asking for field attachments solved it

```
&fields=picture.type(large),attachments
```

Answer (score 0):

The graph api returns response which includes **images** and **webp_images** and it has image links in all available resolutions.

As per the latest version: **v2.12**

For profile photo:

```
/me?fields=photos{picture,images,webp_images}
```

For specific album:

```
'album-id'?fields=photos{picture,images,webp_images}
```

Field details:

**photos**: array of available photos, this will return json like below:

```
{
    data: [],
    pagin: []
}
```

In **data** object we'll get below fields:

**picture**: link for a low resolution image might be for the use of thumbnails

**images**: array of objects for picture image with the different different resolutions in raster format

**webp_images**: array of objects for picture image with the different different resolutions in webp format

**images** and **web_images** object will have data like:

```
{
    height: number, // 400
    source: 'link for the image with the resolution of height and width specified', //https:....
    width: number //496
}
```