# Using facebook graph api how to get news feed with large picture size if the feed type is photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using facebook graph api get News feed:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=...

The picture field it returns is all in smallest size, like picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/xxxxxx4_s.jpg:

Is there any parameter that I can use to retrieve larger thumbnails? Any way to do this?

Comment: I have answered this here hope this will help some one http://stackoverflow.com/a/24681025/1030813

Comment: This is the real answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29009631/347456 (from ClockworkOrange)

Answer (score 43):

You can add custom field list for returning object.

```
?fields=full_picture
```

will return full size image.

Comment: the fields parameter is great, you can filter out the result to show only what you really need like: fields=full_picture,message,link,type,name,description,from

Comment: How to get width and height of the full_picture in the request ifself

Comment: `full_picture` returns image with max width = 720p when in reality the original image can be bigger.

Answer (score 17):

I have found that swapping the characters at the end of the file URL to _n, _b or _o no longer work.

Facebook has released graph API 2.0 which can be used to solve this problem.

Here is the solution:

### 1. Get the object_id from the post you want the image from

In every Post object there maybe an object_id field. This field only appears if the post has a picture of video (i.e. type = 'photo' or 'video')

### 2. Make a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{object_id}?access_token={token}

e.g. if object_id = 123 and your access token = abc then the URL to call becomes https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/123?access_token=abc

This API call gets more information about the given object_id. Since the object_id in this case represents a photo, the response will contain the various versions of the photo.

The response this request can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo

### 3. Take the largest dimensioned image from the images field

The response from the API call has a field names images. This contains small to large sizes of the image. Just take the largest one.

Comment: This is the correct way rather than editing CDN URLs or editing "_n or _s". Great answer with example, works perfectly well with Graph API v2.3

Answer (score 13):

Along with picture field, there is an object_id field.
Put this id in below url:

https://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}/picture

This will return actual size image.
Or you can write this for different image sizes.

https://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}/picture?type=normal

Where type can be : thumbnail, normal, album.

Comment: replacing _s with _n 
and _t with _b also works, but it is not a good practise.

Comment: this is the best solution for now, thnx a lot :)

Comment: Can't find the reference in FB documentation. Any link?

Comment: You can use any Id with the in this URL for pictures [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2],  but post id didn't work because all posts don't have photos. So posts with photos have this object_id node and you can use this to get the picture. I didn't find any specific documentation about this just found out by doing hit and try. And at last this worked

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently searching for the same thing. I know you can swap `_s` for `_n` at the end and get a larger size... but I haven't figured out how to have the api return the larger size on its own.

Comment: no longer working. It use to work all the times but now it is often not working

Answer (score 0):

you can make a extra request with the `[object_id]` of the post entry

```
$res = $facebook->api('/yourid', 'GET', $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even swapping _s for _l or _b might result in a larger thumbnail.

But at times it results in invalid request or a blank image rather a white dot on a dark background.

Ideally the api should specify crop, thumb, normal, and large (like on twitter network)with every picture object on network.

Answer (score 0):

it returns the smallest size i.e., 130x130. to get the bigger size try replacing that with

320x320

480x480

600x600

720x720

Comment: Did not worked for me to change the w=130&h=130 with these numbers (API v 2.5)