# How to get larger version of Facebook's thumbnail images?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Right now the Facebook API is returning a URL like this with all post/album images 130x130 pixels in size:

> [https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10801504_570625556403546_6496651209845129904_n.jpg?oh=dcf8ab3752522532871d2aaab09b6e7e&oe=54E4402F&**gda**=1424027679_76464aeeaa5d232b8100d01476af4ec7](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10801504_570625556403546_6496651209845129904_n.jpg?oh=dcf8ab3752522532871d2aaab09b6e7e&oe=54E4402F&__gda__=1424027679_76464aeeaa5d232b8100d01476af4ec7)

How do I retrieve a full (or any bigger size) image based on that URL?

For example this one:

> [https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p417x417/10801504_570625556403546_6496651209845129904_n.jpg?oh=cd2b5cb0d74f7306c098de9f56dc6e27&oe=54E1F4C1&**gda**=1423830001_e700bfac39039952bfee55b200c158bf](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/p417x417/10801504_570625556403546_6496651209845129904_n.jpg?oh=cd2b5cb0d74f7306c098de9f56dc6e27&oe=54E1F4C1&__gda__=1423830001_e700bfac39039952bfee55b200c158bf)

or anything like that?

All the other suggestions of removing s130x130 from the URL, or /v/t1.0-9/, or replacing _s with _n or anything like that aren't valid any more - I've tried them all (try them yourself if you don't believe me). Is there a way to make this happen? Not sure what Facebook guys have changed to disable that...

Comment: Which API call gave you that URL? You can probably just ask the API for the bigger image in the first place instead of trying to manipulate the URL client side

Comment: it's from a Social Stream plugin: 
 url = url = cp.length > 1 ? 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + cp[1] + '/photos?fields=id,link,from,name,picture,images,comments&limit=' + n : frl + encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=' + id + '&format=rss20');

Comment: What type of Facebook object is cp[1]? user, post, page, etc?

Comment: it's the page ID, and that call returns this:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=352032574929513&format=rss20

as you can see in the resulting page all the images are returned as 130x130 pixel thumbs, and I have no idea how to get the bigger images or if there is an alternate feed to get larger images...

Comment: That page.php endpoint is deprecated and not really part of the API itself - i'll add an answer below showing how to get the full size profile pic for a page post

Comment: Actually, if you're using the pages API to fetch the posts you should already be getting larger images - i think this problem is specific to use of the RSS feed

Comment: well, that's what this script is using, and apparently it's pretty up-to-date (the developer can't figure out a way around it either). If you have a better way of fetching the latest posts off the facebook page wall and larger images, please let me know how.

Comment: Use the pages API itself: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed

Answer (score 3):

After a couple of hours searching and pulling my hair out, I found a solution that works for me. In my case I'm pulling posts from {page-id}/posts, but I'm pretty sure this will work for you too, seeing that I used to get larger images using the same approach as you mention.

This is works for me:

```
bigger_image="https://graph.facebook.com/" + picture_url_from_facebook.match(/_\d+/)[0].slice(1) + "/picture?type=normal";
```

- /_\d+/ matches any substring starting with an underscore (_) followed by any digits (\d matches one digit, \d+ does the digit match over and over until it fails)
- match(regex) returns an array with all strings it could find matching the specified regex
- we grab the first ([0]) element, as this will be an underscore followed by the ID of the picture in Facebook's database
- we slice the string from index 1 to the end, as the underscore is not a part of the ID
- we then get a working link from facebook using the graph api without the need for any extra calls (you can use this in for example an img tag directly)

You can see this working in action @ [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47wyt9t8/)  or [this page we did for a client](http://dreamcatchermusic.com)

Thanks to [Er Adhish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4057535/er-adhish) for leading the way to the solution @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075503/2908761

Answer (score 1):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}/picture?type={thumbnail|album|normal}
```

Example (using a bogus object_id of 122233334444555):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/122233334444555/picture?picture?type=large
```

Make sure object_id is not just the id of an item but it's `object_id` (which is typically the number following the underscore in the full id).

I got those type values from a helpful facebook response message that said:

```
"message": "(#100) type must be one of the following values: thumbnail, album, normal"
```

In place of ?type=... you could do height/width as well:

```
?width=543&height=543
```