# Large images from feed with Open graph V2.2

Tags: facebook

I know this question seems repeated, but I find the solution months ago here.

[How to get the large picture from feed with graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527530/how-to-get-the-large-picture-from-feed-with-graph-api)

But about 4 days ago all the images stop working. It returns "Content not found".

I already try many different ways and I can't find the new real big image. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted an answer to this @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297188/2908761 hope it helps!

Comment: I talk with Facebook and all that solutions are temporal, they recommend me not to use them. I found a permanent solution with API V1.0 I'm looking for a permanent solution in API 2.X