# Get Facebook API full image from object id or image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question :

When I got all the feeds of my profile through API, I got this kind of image url :

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10407901_10205070108129312_6474606199159519359_n.jpg?oh=d7b01585bf8bde8b2f9d498c78ac5710&oe=550CFBE2&**gda**=1427806708_67b3039eb879eb560b7f5b1ea810d1e9](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10407901_10205070108129312_6474606199159519359_n.jpg?oh=d7b01585bf8bde8b2f9d498c78ac5710&oe=550CFBE2&__gda__=1427806708_67b3039eb879eb560b7f5b1ea810d1e9)

This is small picture...

I tried to have full image but I don't success for the moment.

I want this image : (got from the website) [https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10407901_10205070108129312_6474606199159519359_n.jpg?oh=39f3c1443fc0bfea4ba3bd8b4a40dabf&oe=54DE75FB&**gda**=1424108676_aac7e3989dec7a272ae658369cfcd546](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10407901_10205070108129312_6474606199159519359_n.jpg?oh=39f3c1443fc0bfea4ba3bd8b4a40dabf&oe=54DE75FB&__gda__=1424108676_aac7e3989dec7a272ae658369cfcd546)

...but how can I get it from the first link ? or through the object id?

Thanks for your responses

Comment: this url doesn't work : https://graph.facebook.com/10205070108129312/picture?type=large

Comment: I answered this @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877568/how-to-get-larger-version-of-facebooks-thumbnail-images/27297188#27297188

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33765417/264031

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture?type=large

Where at the place of {id} you can put the ID.

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/100005214543942/picture?type=large

Note: Here is the reference to the profile picture so the resolution is quite low. You can put other IDs to get fine large image.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/10205070108129312/picture?type=large = not working for me. Not really, If you can have the url to have the large image with the url of my small image, it will be cool

Comment: Use the following URL: https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=543&height=543

This will work for sure. Here you can set the height and width of the picture.

Comment: This way is not working for me, I have this kind of error 

"message": "(#100) type must be one of the following values: thumbnail, album, normal",

Answer (score 0):

Does the photo endpoint of the graph api help you?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo

Comment: Not really, If you can have the url to have the large image with the url of my small image, it will be cool

Comment: Can someone have a other solution in order to bypass this pb?